# How to create subtotals in a ng-repeat in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm just learning AngularJS and need to create the report below.  I have all the detail lines working well but have no idea how to create the subtotal lines.

Detail lines...

```
<tr data-ng-repeat-start="t in testReferrers">
    <td>{{t.ReferrerName}}</td>
    <td>{{t.AddressLine1}}}</td>
    <td>{{t.DatePlaced  | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</td>
    <td>{{t.InvoiceNumber }}</td>
    <td>{{t.InvoiceAmountLessDiscount | currency : $ : 2 }}</td>
</tr>
```

My first attempt at subtotal line, but I don't know how to calculate {{subTotal}} and how to control when this row shows up.  I need a grouping and group footer capability but don't know how to do that in AngularJS.  I was going to use JQuery to find the subTotalRow and either show or hide...

```
<tr id="subtotalRow" data-ng-repeat-end style="display:none">
    <td colspan=3></td>
    <td style="border-top: solid 1px #000000">Total:</td>
    <td style="border-top: solid 1px #000000">{{subTotal | currency : $ : 2 }}</td>
</tr>
```

Desired output...

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope){
  $scope.data = [
    {Referrer: 'Henry', Amount: 20, Location: 'NY'},
    {Referrer: 'Tom', Amount: 10, Location: 'London'},    
    {Referrer: 'Sam', Amount: 10, Location: 'Paris'},
    {Referrer: 'Henry', Amount: 10, Location: 'NY'},
    {Referrer: 'Tom', Amount: 20, Location: 'London'},    
    {Referrer: 'Henry', Amount: 30, Location: 'NY'}
  ];
  $scope.sum = function(name){
    return $scope.data.filter(function(x) { return x.Referrer == name; })
      .map(function(x) { return x.Amount; }).reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; });
  }
})
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.totalRow{
  border-style: solid;  
}
.total{  
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js">
</script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Referrer</th>
        <th>Location</th>        
        <th>Amount</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-init='next = $index + 1' ng-repeat-start='item in dataSorted = (data | orderBy : "Referrer")'>
        <td>{{item.Referrer}}</td>
        <td>{{item.Location}}</td>
        <td>{{item.Amount}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class='totalRow' ng-repeat-end ng-if='!dataSorted[next] || (dataSorted[next].Referrer != item.Referrer)'>
        <td colspan='2' class='total'>Total:</td>        
        <td>{{sum(item.Referrer)}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, Slava.  I will have to study and understand all of this.  Can you explain the sum function?  I can see the referrer name is passed in and used as a filter.  Not sure what the map part does (since it's amount, it must have something to do with the sum) and I've seen the reduce before and not understood it at all.  Thanks.

Comment: Code snippet returns errors.  I'd love to see it run.

Comment: @DebbieA, try to run snippet again. `$scope.sum`: **1.** `filter` - preserves items with specified `Referrer`, **2.** `map` converts items to their `Amount`, **3.** `reduce` summarize all `Amount` one by one.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I studied up on the filter-map-reduce.  Makes sense.  I've got it all working except for the sum.  I'm getting

Comment: I'm getting   Total: {{sumReferrer(t.ReferrerName)}}  instead of the VALUE of the total.  I'm getting to the sumReferrer function and set an alert to make sure ReferrerName looks correct.  I think the problem is the reduce.

Comment: Here's my sum function:         $scope.sumReferrer = function (refName) {
            alert("refName=" + refName)
            return $scope.data.filter(function (x) { return x.ReferrerName == refName; })
              .map(function (x) { return x.InvoiceAmountAdjusted;}).reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; });

Comment: Same results... Changedcode to             return $scope.data.filter(function (x) { return x.ReferrerName == refName; })
              .map(function (x) { return x.InvoiceAmountAdjusted; }).reduce(function (accumulator, ref) { return accumulator + ref.InvoiceAmountAdjusted });

Comment: @DebbieA, `$scope.data.filter(function (x) { return x.ReferrerName == refName; }) .map(function (x) { return x.InvoiceAmountAdjusted; }).reduce(function (accumulator, ref) { return accumulator + ref});`

Comment: YES!!!!  That was it.  Thanks so very much for sticking with me and teaching me.  I see what I did wrong.  It's working 100%  WOW.  You're wonderful!

Comment: I hope I gave you credit for the correct answer. If not, please tell me what to do.